# Close MS Teams StageView programmatically

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm displaying a third party web page (client page) in a StageView, opened from an AdaptiveCard [tabInfoAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/tabs-link-unfurling#example):

```
{
      type: "invoke",
      title: "open in stageView",
      value: {        
        type: "tab/tabInfoAction",
        tabInfo: {
          contentUrl: "example.com",
          websiteUrl: "example.com",
          name: "View",
          entityId: "entityId",
        },
      },
    }
```

I'd like to close the `stage view` based on a user interaction via `@microsoft/teams-js`. I can do that if displayed in a `task module` by calling `teamsjs.dialog.submit()` in the client code. Is there a similar way to do it in this context?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to close the stage view based on a user interaction via teams-js.

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT - I'm assuming that also means there is no non-teams-js way to close a stage view on an arbitrary user interaction (e.g. clicking a 'submit' button)?

Comment: Yes , there is no other way.